# Javascript three dimensional arrays vs Object literal

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

Which of the following two scenarios performs better and feels more natural to the langauge:

1. Using Object literal:

   ```
   var object = {
       'key1': [e1, e2, e3, e4, .., en],
       'key2': [e1, e2, e3, e4, .., en],
       'key3': [e1, e2, e3, e4, .., en],
       ...,
       'keyn': [e1, e2, e3, e4, .., en]
   }
   ```
2. Using 2 dimensional array (with unique 1st element on the 2nd dimension)

   ```
   var array = [
       ['key1', [e1, e2, e3, e4, .., en],
       ['key2', [e1, e2, e3, e4, .., en],
       ['key3', [e1, e2, e3, e4, .., en],
       ...,
       ['keyn', [e1, e2, e3, e4, .., en]
   ];
   ```

If the main purpose of the data structure is pure iteration over key1, key2, key3, .., keyn and perform some actions on each e1, e2, e3, .., en.

Note: not sure if relevant, but those 2 structures aren't defined as is during initializing. `object[key] = [e1, ..];` and `array.push([key, [e1, ..]);` are used all over the system before iteration and processing are required.

**Edit:**
Throughout the application, I'll be needing to access the array (`[e1, e2, .., en]`) to push more elements to it. I'll be needing to do, of course, by the string key.

So I guess there are 2 parts of it, adding elements, and iterating over them.

Comment: The question is whether you need access to elements by string key or not. Arrays and hashtables have different algorithmic complexity for different tasks, one it not 'faster' or 'more natural', in general, than the other. Based on your description, I'd go with arrays.

Comment: performance wise for known keys, i would take the object version. if you need to iterate over all elements, then take the array version.

Comment: @NinaScholz They directly stated *"the main purpose of the data structure is pure iteration over key1, key2, key3, .., keyn and perform some actions on each e1, e2, e3, .., en."*. So they may want to go with the array version, but the difference is quite small between them. This question is more opinion based.

Comment: So if the array version is chosen, than `key1...n` will become the index, so a simple two dimensional array is sufficient.

Comment: Per your update you need to go with an object that has arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array would be slightly faster in this context, but not to any noticeable extent, iterating over each of these would essentially be the same.

Array iteration

```html
for(var i in array){//i is the index of the array
  keyName = array[i][0];
  arrayOfValues = array[i][1];
}
```

Object iteration

```html
for(var i in object){//i is the keyname
  key = i;
  arrayOfValues = object[i];
}
```

But if you are using the keyid to find and append to the inner array I would go with the object.

Finding by keyid in array

```html
var keyId = "key123456";
var arrayOfValues=null;
for(var i in array){
  if(array[i][0] == keyId){
    arrayOfValues = array[i][1];
    break;
  }
}
```

Finding by keyid in object

```html
var keyId = "key123456"
var arrayOfValues = object[keyId]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a object literal because you won't need to initialize more arrays, so the performance may be better, but that depends on the way you're doing the things.

If you want to declare a array, you could declare all the elements in the same array where goes the element that declares the name of itself, so you skip the first index (0) for iterating the array. Idea:

```
var array = [
    ['key1', 1, 2, 3, 4, 9],
    ['key2', 1, 2, 3, 4, 9],
    ['key3', 1, 2, 3, 4, 9],
    ['keyn', 1, 2, 3, 4, 9]
];

for(var i = 0, el; el = array[i]; i ++) {
    for(var b = 1, len = el.length; b < len; b ++) {
        console.log(el[b]);
    }
}
```

I think that's almost the same thing of declaring a object, but arrays, besides having the `Object` constructor, they have the `Array` constructor, then I "believe" it'd be more slow for the performane than declaring a object literal.